# git tags versus branches for application releases

Tags: git

I'm using Git, Maven, Jenkins & Nexus as my source code/build/release infrastructure. Can anyone provide pro's and con's of using tags or branches to represent application releases?

It seems using tags is a preferred approach, but the articles I've read lean towards using lightweight instead of annotated tags in their solutions. Also I get a sense that tags are mainly useful for developers as a temporary 'marker' for code changes, instead of an an authoritative marker/place in time that a release has to be.

My understanding of lightweight tags is they can be deleted or moved between commits. This seem (to me) to invalidate the whole idea of using them to define what's in a release, whereas a created branch is pretty set in stone (obviously files on it can be edited later, but the creation of it is immovable.)

Thanks for any info/advice.
Dave

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a branch being set in stone, git does not record when/where you created a branch, it only stores what it currently points to.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen re: my comment about branches, when you create a branch, it has a specific commit id, and info that doesn't change, so it's essentially a permanent record of the code base at a specific point in time. When you compare that with a tag, the tag is associated with a commit, but, in the case of lightweight tags, they can be moved to another commit later.

Comment: Where is that branch information stored? That's news to me, as far as I know, the only knowledge git has about a branch is which commit it is currently pointing to, which obviously does change when you add more commits to it.

Comment: When a branch is created, it has a commit id, just like any other change to a repo. Additional changes can be made on the branch after that; my point here though is that the commit id from the branch's initial creation can't/won't change, which make it ideal for identifying the code base in place when the branch was created. My concern with using tags is a tag is basically a pointer to a commit; for lightweight tags, those can be moved from one commit to another, hence my concern about using them to identify application releases.

Comment: And again, I want to know where this is stored, because this information would be useful to have, but everything I know about how git works tells me you're wrong. A branch is tracked with 1 reference and 1 reference only, and that is where it is currently pointing, not where it was created. And yes, tags can be moved or deleted because they are not part of the history, they're besides the history and thus you can change them without affecting history.

Comment: And you're right, when you create a branch, it refers to the commit where you started the branch but as soon as you start committing to this new branch, it moves with the commits. If git had any notion of where the branch was started, a lot of the commands in git, such as rebase, would be much simpler, but they aren't, they have to figure out which commits you want to rebase even when you mention all the involved branches, which again tells me that this information is wrong.

Comment: In essence, I don't believe you have any set-in-stone options other than commits that are part of the history. Tags can be moved, and deleted, same with branches.

Answer (score 2):

If you maintain only one version, then use tags.

If you want to maintain different major versions then use one branch for each major version and tags for minor versions.